# simplest way to sort a list of Vector3's

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine

So I have a unique question. Say I have the following code:

```
List<Vector3> locations = new List<Vector3> ();

locations.add(new Vector3(1,1,0));
locations.add(new Vector3(1,2,0));
locations.add(new Vector3(1,3,0));
locations.add(new Vector3(2,1,0));
locations.add(new Vector3(3,2,0));
locations.add(new Vector3(3,8,0));
```

and now I want to sort this list and remove items based on the fact that I ONLY want items in my list that are the lowest y for each x value represented.

So after the sorting code the only Vector3's I'll have in the example list above are:

```
1,1,0
2,1,0
3,2,0
```

Thanks ahead for any help!

Comment: Could you use a simple `.GroupBy(v => v.x).Select(g => g.Min())` or something along those lines? I think you should expand on your deletion criteria and update the question title--that's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to get the correct sorting path I wanted. If there is a more efficient way let me know.

```
List<int> index = new List<int> ();

index.Clear ();

foreach (Vector3 location in locations) {
    foreach (Vector3 comparedLocation in locations) {
        if (location == comparedLocation) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((location.x == comparedLocation.x) && (location.y > comparedLocation.y)) {
            int id = missingLocations.IndexOf (location);
            index.Add (id);
        }
    }
}

index.Sort ();
index = index.Distinct ().ToList ();

for (int i = index.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int id = index [i];
    locations.RemoveAt (id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Using `List<Vector3>`

```
locations = locations.OrderBy(v => v.x).ToList();
```

### Using `Vector3[]`

You can simply sort the locations `Vector3[]` in x ascending order using:

```
locations = locations.OrderBy(v => v.x).ToArray<Vector3>();
```

Comment: I'm storing them in a list since I don't know how many variables will be added through the code I have already. An array would work just fine if I knew how many Vector3's there would be in it. A list allows me some more  freedom.

Comment: See my updated answer for implementation using List<Vector3>